# Upper bounding the largest singular value of a matrix $X$ via LMI — is it correct?

Tags: matrices, block-matrices, linear-matrix-inequality, spectral-norm, schur-complement

For $z \in \Bbb C$ and $\delta > 0$, the inequality $|z| < \delta$ is equivalent to the matrix inequality

$$\begin{bmatrix} -\delta & z\\ z^* & -\delta \end{bmatrix} \prec 0$$

(Source: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781118577325.app1)

and I believe this because

\begin{align}
|z| < \delta 
&\Leftrightarrow \frac{|z|^2}{\delta^2} < 1 \\
&\Leftrightarrow 1 - \frac{zz^*}{\delta^2} > 0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow -\delta - z(-\delta)^{-1}z^* < 0 \quad (\text{multiplying $-\delta$)} \\
&\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
-\delta & z\\
z^* & -\delta
\end{bmatrix} \prec 0 \quad (\text{by Schur complement formula}).
\end{align}

Also, for a matrix $X \in \mathbb{C}^{p\times q}$, we have $\|X\| < 1$ equivalent to

$$\begin{bmatrix} I & X\\ X^* & I\end{bmatrix} \succ 0$$

---

#### Question

I want to know if the analogous result for a matrix is true, that is, is the following true?

$$\|X\| < \delta \Leftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix} -\delta I & X\\ X^* & -\delta I \end{bmatrix} \prec 0$$

---

#### Attempt

\begin{align}
\|X\| < \delta 
&\Leftrightarrow \frac{\sigma_{max}(X)}{\delta} < 1 \\
&\Leftrightarrow \lambda_{max}\big(\frac{XX^{*}}{\delta^2}\big) < 1 \\
&\Leftrightarrow \delta^2 - \lambda_{max}\big({XX^{*}}\big) > 0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow \lambda_{min}\big(\delta^2 I - XX^{*}\big) > 0\\
&\Leftrightarrow \delta^2 I - XI^{-1}X^{*} \succ 0 \tag{1} \\
&\Leftrightarrow -\delta I - X(-\delta I)^{-1}X^{*} \prec 0 \quad (\text{multiplying $-\frac{1}{\delta}$}) \\
&\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
-\delta I & X\\
X^* & -\delta I
\end{bmatrix} \prec 0 \quad \tag{2}(\text{by Schur complement formula}).
\end{align}

However, from page 184 of S. Boyd's Convex Optimization text, ([https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf#page184](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf#page184)), we can see that the condition $(1)$ above is equivalent to $\begin{bmatrix} \delta I & X\\ X^* & \delta I \end{bmatrix} \succ 0$.

Multiplying by $-1$ from this statement, we have $\begin{bmatrix} -\delta I & -X \\ -X^* & -\delta I \end{bmatrix} \prec 0. \tag{3}$

Is there anything wrong with my derivation? Or can it be that both $(2)$ and $(3)$ are equivalent?

Comment: I don't understand why you multiplied by $-\delta$. The first LMI looks wrong to me.

Comment: You mean the LMI for $z$? I am multiplying by negative delta to change the direction of inequality and to get (1,1) and (2,2) component to be that value.

Comment: The LMI is from page 4 of https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781118577325.app1. I am trying to fill the gaps for it.

Comment: Why change the direction so early? Wait till the end and multiply by $-1$. You get a different result. Hence, one of us is wrong.

Comment: Could you please check out A1.15 from the link above? q=0 on this case, do you get a different LMI?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, if I do multiply -1 at the end, I also have $-z$ and $-z^*$. Is it be possible that both LMIs are true?

Comment: Indeed, it seems that both are true.

Comment: If both LMIs are equivalent, I am curious about how to interpret it. I suspect that maybe it is because the given inequality is geographically a ball, symmetric about the origin? But then I am really not confident.

Comment: In the $2 \times 2$ case, the equivalence is due to $(-1)^2 = 1$.